# jQuery hover event on <a> tag on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, hover

The jQuery `.hover()` event seems to work fine on mobile devices (testing it on iOS 5.1 Safari) as long as it's not on a anchor element `<a>`. Work fine means it will trigger the hover handler that is bound on it.

But, when the hover event is on `<a>`, the browser is redirected to the URL from `href` instead.

I want it to hover first on first touch (run the event handler) before it's being redirected (trigger the click) on second touch. Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add an event handler to the link that changes something about the DOM (like toggling a class to change background colors, etc.)

From the [Mobile Safari docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html):

> Mouse events are delivered in the same order you'd expect in other web
>   browsers illustrated in Figure 6-4. If the user taps a nonclickable
>   element, no events are generated. If the user taps a clickable
>   element, events arrive in this order: mouseover, mousemove, mousedown,
>   mouseup, and click. The mouseout event occurs only if the user taps on
>   another clickable item. Also, if the contents of the page changes on
>   the mousemove event, no subsequent events in the sequence are sent.
>   This behavior allows the user to tap in the new content

[image: Figure 6-4]

Comment: I still don't understand what it means by "changes" because I've tried many things (included the one you suggested) but still unable to stop it from triggering the click event. Any elaboration on that? Thanks

Comment: To hinder it from clicking add the parameter e and set e.preventDefault(); in the function provided to the hover(); For the other part I'm not entirely sure I understand what you want to achieve. I made a tinker here: https://tinker.io/ff4ab is this what you want?

Comment: @limelights, I still need it to redirect, but on the second touch. it's a drop down menu. So, first touch should open the sub menus, and second touch only will redirect.

Comment: http://www.universityvw.net/ has menus at the top that should act like what you are thinking. I wrote the code that drives those menus using the technique mentioned above.