# jQuery mobile equivalent for mouseover

Tags: android, jquery, hover, equivalent

I have a function that is activated among a series of thumbnail img tabs when the cursor hovers.

The images are display:block and position:absolute and the location (top) and size change on mouseover.

How can I reproduce the same on Android or iPhone/iPad Safari.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696533/jquery-hover-event-on-a-tag-on-mobile-devices

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to bind a `tap` event to the thumbnails rather than `mouseover`. I believe Safari on iOS may already interpret hover events as taps/clicks, so there'll be no need to do anything in those cases, but that may only apply to the CSS `:hover` pseudoclass, not `mouseover`.

Answer (score -1):

@Didier Levy in android since there is no cursor u cannot give it that similar effect ..

what u can do is, u can use some .xml files and change the button background and much more with it

first make an new android .xml files in bg_button.xml into your project's res/drawable directory

contents will be

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/bg_button_ov" /> <!-- pressed -->

<item android:state_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/bg_button_ov" /> <!-- focused -->

<item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_button_n" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

use the     @drawable resource for that effect you want

now at to **add this effect to a button**

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_save"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"


        android:background="@drawable/bg_button" <!-- drawable resource used here-->

        android:text="@string/Save"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```