# Jquery animation isn't initialised on mobile

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mobile, page-refresh

I'm changing the opacity of a class by using the jQuery hover function.
Note : I'm not using the

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js">
</script>
```

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".thumbnail_image_related_project .transparent_font").css({'opacity' : '0'});
        $(".thumbnail_image_related_project").hover(
            function(){
                $(this).children(".transparent_font").stop().animate({'opacity' : '0.7'}, 300); 
             },
            function(){
                $(this).children(".transparent_font").stop().animate({'opacity' : '0'}, 300); 
           }
        );
    });
</script>
```

This code is working perfectly on a laptop but not on a smartphone.
The problem: When I clicked on the element, the animation is working and I'm going to next page. But, when I going back to the previous page, the opacity of the element isn't initialised.
Does some one know why?

Here is my php code:

```
<a href="http://192.168.0.11/next-page/" title="blabla">
   <div class="thumbnail_image_related_project">
      <h2 class="transparent_font">Text and the white background</h2>
      <div id="image">
         <img width="300" height="173" src="http://192.168.0.11/blabla.jpg"/>
      </div>
   </div>
</a>
```

here is my css:

```
    .thumbnail_image_related_project .transparent_font{
    line-height: 1.25em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: black;
    background-color:white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: You try to use hover in a touch interface ?

Comment: i don't think its possible currently.

Comment: @Romain How do you trigger hover on a touch screen?

Comment: My android phone supports `hover` ([floating touch](http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/technologies/floating-touch/))

Comment: The hover function is working for the mobile but not the callback function of my jquery animation. When I'm refreshing the page, I don't  get any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQuery or jQuery Mobile? The reason I ask is that on mobile, it is likely a touchstart event not hover. jQuery Mobile may convert touchstart into hover.

Take a look at this: [jQuery hover event on  tag on mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696533/jquery-hover-event-on-a-tag-on-mobile-devices).

Comment: I don't think you can use both at the same time. I've updated my answer with a link.