# jquery preventdefault on first touch only

Tags: jquery, mobile, hover, preventdefault

I'm hoping to learn a way to code the following for touch only, using jquery?

```
$(".portfolio a").one("click", false);
```

This code is for a `hover` event on a visual menu link. I'd like to prevent the link following through on the first touch, so the hover event happens on the first touch, and a second touch takes you through to the link.

Hover class is tied to href...

Comment: Have you looked into this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696533/jquery-hover-event-on-a-tag-on-mobile-devices)

Comment: Thanks Vidhuran, I was really interested to see if there was a one-click-false (or preventdefault) equivalent in jquery for touch-only...seems like if there were, it would be the most straightforward solution to the hover issue that abounds...

Answer (score 4):

Just test for touch behaviour before unbinding the link once:

```
if ("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement) {
   $(".portfolio a").one("click", false, function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
   }
}
```

or vice versa

```
$(".portfolio a").one("click", false, function(e){
   if ("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement) {
     e.preventDefault();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I have been looking since yesterday how to get my dropdown menus working nicely on touch devices and have seen all sorts of complex solutions. And then I found your answer - it is such a simple solution and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

It might be more natural to add a `.hover` class, rather than using a `:hover` pseudo-selector.  That would enable you to do the following:

```
$(".portfolio a").one("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('hover');
});
```

The next click would then behave as usual.

Comment: Thanks jmar777 - still appears to affect mouse click, though. Looking for solution that will only affect touch device behavior (original css hover is working for mouse).

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure you'll be able to differentiate based on the event alone.  To the best of my knowledge you'd need to combine some mobile-detection logic to determine which behavior to use.  There's a W3C spec for touch events that should help with this kind of problem, but I believe it's still in "last call" status.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much jmar777, I will look into another approach to resolve!

Comment: For the record you typed "one" instead of "on".

Comment: @JonathanOsborn `.one()` was intentional, actually. It allows you to register an event handler (similar to `.on()`), but the handler will only be invoked the first time the corresponding event is triggered. This was the behavior requested in the original question.

Comment: Right you are. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".portfolio a").one("click", false, function(event){

event.preventDefault();

};);
```

Try this

Comment: Why the `false` data parameter?

Comment: Lol, yes. I don't think it was valid in the original code, though.

Comment: Thanks Samitha, this seems to have the same effect on the mouse though...I'm hoping to find a solution for touch only...